# What is correct way to declare varbinary in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, varbinary

What is correct way to declare `varbinary` in SQL Server 2008? Now I declaring like this

```
    DECLARE @BinaryValue varbinary(MAX)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426756/using-variable-to-specify-size-when-declaring-a-varbinary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is like this:

```
DECLARE @BinaryValue varbinary(MAX)
```

Consider specifying a length instead of `MAX`, if you can.