# How to incorporate a variable as the SIZE argument of VARCHAR in an SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I am not an SQL Server expert, by any means, but have enough knowledge to make me dangerous.  I've spent hours searching the internet and could not find a valid example of what I am trying to accomplish here.  Can someone please explain to me why the following code is failing?  This, of course, is not its final usage, but I have simplified the code to clearly demonstrate the problem.

Below are copies of the SQL code and their results:

**Query:**

```sql
DECLARE @MaxLength AS INT    
SELECT @MaxLength = 45    
SELECT CAST(site_name AS VARCHAR(@MaxLength)) FROM sites
```

**Messages:**

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '@MaxLength'.

When I substitute a literal integer (e.g., 45) in place of the local variable (@MaxLength), it works fine, as indicated below:

**Query:**

```sql
--DECLARE @MaxLength AS INT    
--SELECT @MaxLength = 45    
SELECT CAST(site_name AS VARCHAR(45)) FROM sites
```

**Messages:**

> (1550 row(s) affected)

As stated above, I simplified the code example for the purpose of clarity, but the final code block will present multiple column output and is bound for an 8 1/2 x 11 sheet of paper.
My aim is to force the column widths of the output to the smallest width possible without truncation of the data.  This is why VARCHAR(MAX) is not a solution.  Below is a larger chunk of the code that will appear in the final query, and this may clarify what I'm attempting to accomplish:

```sql
DECLARE @MaxLength AS INT
SET @MaxLength = (SELECT MAX(LEN(site_name)) FROM sites)
SELECT CAST(site_name AS VARCHAR(@MaxLength)) AS site_name, CAST(customer_name AS CHAR(40)) AS customer_name, CAST(remote_agent_name AS CHAR(35)) AS RA_Name, CAST(subtype_name AS CHAR(20)) AS subtype_name
FROM sites, customers, remote_agent, remote_agent_subtype
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I think you'll need dynamic SQL to achieve this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426756

Comment: This is a bit strange but since it is varchar you could just cast is as varchar(max). Then you don't have to worry about the length at all.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use dynamic sql to accomplish this.

However, as the Aaron Bertrand stated in the link Bridge shared, it's hard to imagine a good reason to do this rather than just use a large number you know you'll never exceed, such as 8000 or MAX.

Comment: heh I hadn't looked at the linked thread but had the same idea. Good to know that I in line with him. :)

Comment: That's fine, but why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're describing, I wonder if there is a more direct answer.

If you want to trim down a column during a SELECT, why not

```
SUBSTRING()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748(v=sql.105).aspx

So if you want to make sure it is also as small as possible (the point of varchar), certainly you can put an RTrim on as well...

```
declare @caseMaxLen int;
select @caseMaxLen = 3;

select 
    rtrim(substring('mystring', 1, @caseMaxLen))
```

If you want to error on truncation, just check that separately in advance.
If there a maximum, then there is a maximum... you'll have to check that if you want to know.